# Max(date) from multiple tables - sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a set of tables(approx 100) which have the column - date. I want to get the max date for every table followed by the table name. the final structure should look like this:

```
Tablename   Date
rftr        2020-02-31
dTCM        2020-04-12
item        2014-09-12
test        2019-04-30
```

I am using the following code to dynamically take the tablename and print out the max date:

```
DECLARE @RowsToProcess  int
DECLARE @CurrentRow     int


DECLARE @table1 TABLE (RowID int not null primary key identity(1,1), col1 nvarchar(max) )  

insert into @table1  values ('rftr')
insert into @table1  values ('dTCM')
insert into @table1  values ('item ')


SET @RowsToProcess=@@ROWCOUNT

SET @CurrentRow=0
WHILE @CurrentRow<=@RowsToProcess
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SelectCol nvarchar(max)
    SET @CurrentRow=@CurrentRow+1
    set @SelectCol = (SELECT 
        col1
        FROM @table1
        WHERE RowID=@CurrentRow
        )
    
    exec('select max(date) from ' + @SelectCol )
    

END
```

On running this query, i only get the max date. I am unable to add the table name as another column. I tried using:

```
exec('select max(pdw_last_updated), ' + @selectcol + 'as tb from ' + @SelectCol )
```

But i am getting the error:
The multi-part identifier "rftr" could not be bound.

I am getting this error for every table in @table1.
Can someone suggest the right approach to get the tablename with the max(date).

Comment: I think you need to put the value into quotes in the select statement, now it assumes it’s a column or other value and can’t find it

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a `WHILE` loop. You can query `Sys.Tables` to get the table names
assuming that all your tables has the column `Date`

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @SQL = STRING_AGG(
                  CONCAT(N'SELECT MAX([Date]),',
                         QUOTENAME(Name, ''''),
                         ' TableName FROM [', Name, ']'), ' UNION ')
FROM Sys.Tables;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b93e4aeada6c55045261094adb14bf91)